# How to use the Spring Security Facelets tag library in JSF

Tags: spring, jsf, jakarta-ee, spring-security

i want to use The **Spring Security Facelets tag library** to secure my UI components
in my **JSF 2** pages

i have following dependencies for spring security version 3.0.5:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

i configured **applicationSecurity.xml** to make spring security login, and it works fine
with UserDetailsService, and when tried to add the security definition:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ice="http://www.icesoft.com/icefaces/component"
    xmlns:pretty="http://ocpsoft.com/prettyfaces" 
    xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags">
```

and when running the application, i got following error:

```
Warning: This page calls for XML namespace http://www.springframework.org/security/tags declared with prefix sec but no taglibrary exists for that namespace.
```

Ref: http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/petclinic-tutorial.html

please advise.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You will need to add **springsecurity.taglib.xml** first
as mentioned here:

http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/webflow/2.3.x/reference/html/spring-faces.html#spring-faces-security-taglib

and you should have the **org.springframework.faces** jar in your classpath in order to use it.

then use the security tags as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE composition PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional/<!DOCTYPE composition PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags">
```

[Reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring-webflow/docs/2.2.x/reference/html/ch13s09.html)

Comment: I am developing JSF pages, and it's extension is .xhtml.

Comment: when i try to add above tag inside the head i am getting following error: `The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup`

Comment: any ideas what jars required to use the springsecurity.taglib.xml ?

Comment: it works fine after following the documentation link for facelets http://static.springsource.org/spring-webflow/docs/2.2.x/reference/html/ch13s09.html and i have to use the following dependency too: 

    <dependency>
              <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
              <artifactId>org.springframework.faces</artifactId>
              <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
          </dependency>

Comment: please update the answer and remove the jsp include and add the dependency so i can mark it as correct answer.

Answer (score 14):

Successfully implemented:

On top of your normal Spring Security dependencies you'll need the following two additional Maven dependencies

```
        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-faces</artifactId>
           <version>2.4.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

in your POM file.

For JSF 2 save the following as /WEB-INF/springsecurity.taglib.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE facelet-taglib PUBLIC
  "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Facelet Taglib 1.0//EN"
  "http://java.sun.com/dtd/facelet-taglib_1_0.dtd">
<facelet-taglib>
    <namespace>http://www.springframework.org/security/tags</namespace>
    <tag>
        <tag-name>authorize</tag-name>
        <handler-class>org.springframework.faces.security.FaceletsAuthorizeTagHandler</handler-class>
    </tag>
    <function>
        <function-name>areAllGranted</function-name>
        <function-class>org.springframework.faces.security.FaceletsAuthorizeTagUtils</function-class>
        <function-signature>boolean areAllGranted(java.lang.String)</function-signature>
    </function>
    <function>
        <function-name>areAnyGranted</function-name>
        <function-class>org.springframework.faces.security.FaceletsAuthorizeTagUtils</function-class>
        <function-signature>boolean areAnyGranted(java.lang.String)</function-signature>
    </function>
    <function>
        <function-name>areNotGranted</function-name>
        <function-class>org.springframework.faces.security.FaceletsAuthorizeTagUtils</function-class>
        <function-signature>boolean areNotGranted(java.lang.String)</function-signature>
    </function>
    <function>
        <function-name>isAllowed</function-name>
        <function-class>org.springframework.faces.security.FaceletsAuthorizeTagUtils</function-class>
        <function-signature>boolean isAllowed(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)</function-signature>
    </function>
</facelet-taglib>
```

Register the above file in web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_LIBRARIES</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/springsecurity.taglib.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

It will resolve no taglibrary exists warning and now you are ready to use the tag library in your views. You can use the authorize tag to include nested content conditionally:

```
<!DOCTYPE composition PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags">

    <sec:authorize ifAllGranted="ROLE_FOO, ROLE_BAR">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    </sec:authorize>

    <sec:authorize ifNotGranted="ROLE_FOO, ROLE_BAR">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    </sec:authorize>

    <sec:authorize ifAnyGranted="ROLE_FOO, ROLE_BAR">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    </sec:authorize>

</ui:composition>
```

REFERENCE: https://docs.spring.io/spring-webflow/docs/2.3.x/reference/html/spring-faces.html#spring-faces-security-taglib

Answer (score 2):

It's not as easy with JSF as it is with Spring MVC...

But you can find a way to do it in this bug report

https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SWF-1333

last message from Rossen Stoyanchev