# spring security jsf/facelets tag library no tag "authentication"

Tags: authentication, tags, spring-security

I'm new to spring security. I use the JSF Framework too. In the xhtml page I use spring security tags. This one works :

```jsp
<sec:authorize access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')">HOHO</sec:authorize>
```

However, these ones don't work :

```jsp
<sec:authentication property="name" />
<sec:authentication property="principal.name" />
<sec:authentication property="principal" />
```

And it gives me this error:

```
/Welcome.xhtml @20,48 <sec:authentication> Tag Library supports namespace: http://www.springframework.org/security/tags, but no tag was defined for name: authentication
```

**Edit**
I tried to add this in the springsecurity.taglib.xml :

```
<tag>
  <tag-name>authentication</tag-name>
  <handler-class>org.springframework.security.taglibs.authz.AuthenticationTag</handler-class>
</tag>
```

AND this :

```
<tag>
   <tag-name>authentication</tag-name>
   <component>
        <component-type>org.springframework.security.taglibs.authz.AuthenticationTag</component-type>
   </component>
</tag>
```

But none of them worked for me.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7915134/how-to-use-the-spring-security-facelets-tag-library-in-jsf.

Comment: Hi Ritesh! Well, I've already went through that link while having a problem in non-recognizing the namespace "sec". But now the problem is different.. The namespace is recognised the reason for which sec:authorize works fine, but sec:authentification is not recognised. This is my exact problem. Thank you again.

Comment: ok. do you have "authentication" tag-name in springsecurity.taglib.xml? I guess a few versions ago, there was no tag "authentication" in the spring security jsf/facelets tag library.

Comment: Wow! You are AWSOME! I thumb up for your cleverness! Could you please tell me what I should add in springsecurity.taglib.xml? Thank you! I tried this : <tag>
                <tag-name>authentication</tag-name>
                <handler-class>org.springframework.security.authentication</handler-class>
        </tag> and it didnt work...

Comment: <handler-class> takes full class name and so obviously it won't work. Did you try #{request.userPrincipal.name}?

Comment: Thank you so much! That did the necessary. So maybe that's why they eliminated "authentication" tag.. due to redundancy.