# spring security 3 isAuthenticated() not working

Tags: jsf-2, spring-security

Sorry for my english. Why does not working method `isAuthenticated()` in Spring security? I use in JSF:

```
#{loginMB.authentication.authenticated}

<sec:authorize access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">
    test
</sec:authorize>
```

It is not working. All time it return `true`, if I authenticated or not.

If showing a roles:

```
#{loginMB.authentication.authorities}
```

It is show right, when is authenticated a role is `[ROLE_ADMIN]`, when is not authenticated a role is `[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]`.

When is problem?

**==== Updated ====**

If create metod `isAuthenticated()` in `LoginBean` for check `AnonymousAuthenticationToken` as said Aleksandr:

```
public boolean isAuthenticated(){

    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    return authentication != null && !(authentication instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken) && authentication.isAuthenticated();

}
```

It is working. Thank you Aleksandr. But authorize tag is not working. If I add in a JSF page:

```
<sec:authorize access="hasRole('ROLE_ANONYMOUS')">
    ROLE_ANONYMOUS
</sec:authorize>
<sec:authorize access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">
    ROLE_ADMIN
</sec:authorize>
```

It print ROLE_ANONYMOUS and ROLE_ADMIN. Why?

**==== Updated 2 ====**

applicationContext-security.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <beans:import resource="applicationContext.xml"/>


    <global-method-security jsr250-annotations="enabled" />

    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <form-login login-page="/pages/login.html" authentication-failure-url="/fail.html"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll" />

    </http>

    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="UserDAO">
            <password-encoder hash="plaintext" />
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

Comment: It is working fine. You just need to check for `AnonymousAuthenticationToken` if you want to use this method.

Comment: I created metod isAuthenticated() in LoginBean for check AnonymousAuthenticationToken, it is work. But spring security authorize tag not working.

Comment: I added to main post in section 'updated', what i mean.

Comment: The `access` attribute takes expressions.

Comment: If you mean `hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')` it is not working. I edited main post.

Comment: can you also post your spring-security config file

Comment: I added spring-security config file in main post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem solved.

1. If create metod isAuthenticated() in LoginBean for check AnonymousAuthenticationToken as said Aleksandr:

   ```
      public boolean isAuthenticated(){

          Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
          return authentication != null && !(authentication instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken) && authentication.isAuthenticated();

      }
   ```

   It is working. Thank you Aleksandr.
2. For will work authorize tag in JSF page to read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15378140/2691739). And i had [it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19260524/2691739) problem.