# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.faces.security.FaceletsAuthorizeTagHandler

Tags: jsf, spring-security, facelets, spring-webflow

I trying to add Spring Security Facelets Tag Library as it is written [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-webflow/docs/2.3.x/reference/html/ch13s11.html).

I added in web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_LIBRARIES</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/springsecurity.taglib.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

I added in springsecurity.taglib.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE facelet-taglib PUBLIC
  "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Facelet Taglib 1.0//EN"
  "http://java.sun.com/dtd/facelet-taglib_1_0.dtd">
<facelet-taglib>
    <namespace>http://www.springframework.org/security/tags</namespace>
    <tag>
        <tag-name>authorize</tag-name>
        <handler-class>org.springframework.faces.security.FaceletsAuthorizeTagHandler</handler-class>
    </tag>
    <function>
        <function-name>areAllGranted</function-name>
        <function-class>org.springframework.faces.security.FaceletsAuthorizeTagUtils</function-class>
        <function-signature>boolean areAllGranted(java.lang.String)</function-signature>
    </function>
    <function>
        <function-name>areAnyGranted</function-name>
        <function-class>org.springframework.faces.security.FaceletsAuthorizeTagUtils</function-class>
        <function-signature>boolean areAnyGranted(java.lang.String)</function-signature>
    </function>
    <function>
        <function-name>areNotGranted</function-name>
        <function-class>org.springframework.faces.security.FaceletsAuthorizeTagUtils</function-class>
        <function-signature>boolean areNotGranted(java.lang.String)</function-signature>
    </function>
    <function>
        <function-name>isAllowed</function-name>
        <function-class>org.springframework.faces.security.FaceletsAuthorizeTagUtils</function-class>
        <function-signature>boolean isAllowed(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)</function-signature>
    </function>
</facelet-taglib>
```

I added in pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-faces</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

But it is not working. It print next error:

```
[#|2013-10-09T02:20:00.122+0300|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.tools.admin.org.glassfish.deployment.admin|_ThreadID=59;_ThreadName=Thread-10;|Exception while invoking class com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication start method
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.faces.security.FaceletsAuthorizeTagHandler
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:138)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:130)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:269)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:294)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:462)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:382)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:355)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:370)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1064)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:96)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1244)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1232)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:209)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:168)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:238)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
|#]
```

Where is problem? Library spring-faces added in pom.xml.

Comment: I don't do Spring, but to my best of knowledge, "Spring Security" is absolutely not the same as "Spring WebFlow". The taglib you're looking for is not in Spring WebFlow.

Comment: Right, the WebFlow Faces lib is documented here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-webflow/docs/2.0-m1/reference/spring-faces.html It's thus very definitely not the same. You need a different Maven coordinate for the Spring Security Facelets taglib.

Comment: I want to use [Spring Security authorize tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19221979/spring-security-3-isauthenticated-not-working) in JSF, but it is not working. And I try to use as it is written [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15378140/2691739).

Comment: I created a new project and it is working but in the old project it is not working. I do not understand where is problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. Problem was in IDE, I created a new project and it helped.

And I removed dependency `spring-security-taglibs`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: you removed org.springframework.webflow right? And not taglibs