# Exception when integrate Spring Security inside ui:composition

Tags: spring-security

I'm trying to integrate Spring Security inside ui:composition.
I'm getting help from this helpful link : https://raichand-java.blogspot.in/2016/12/springsecurity4primefaces5springdatajpa.html

It works as well.

But, after integrating the code inside ui:composition, I got an exception.
Knowing that I added the file **springsecurity.taglib.xml**:

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE facelet-taglib PUBLIC
  "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Facelet Taglib 1.0//EN"
  "http://java.sun.com/dtd/facelet-taglib_1_0.dtd">
<facelet-taglib>
    <namespace>http://www.springframework.org/security/tags</namespace>
    <tag>
        <tag-name>authorize</tag-name>
        <handler-class>org.springframework.faces.security.FaceletsAuthorizeTagHandler</handler-class>
    </tag>
    <function>
        <function-name>areAllGranted</function-name>
        <function-class>org.springframework.faces.security.FaceletsAuthorizeTagUtils</function-class>
        <function-signature>boolean areAllGranted(java.lang.String)</function-signature>
    </function>
    <function>
        <function-name>areAnyGranted</function-name>
        <function-class>org.springframework.faces.security.FaceletsAuthorizeTagUtils</function-class>
        <function-signature>boolean areAnyGranted(java.lang.String)</function-signature>
    </function>
    <function>
        <function-name>areNotGranted</function-name>
        <function-class>org.springframework.faces.security.FaceletsAuthorizeTagUtils</function-class>
        <function-signature>boolean areNotGranted(java.lang.String)</function-signature>
    </function>
    <function>
        <function-name>isAllowed</function-name>
        <function-class>org.springframework.faces.security.FaceletsAuthorizeTagUtils</function-class>
        <function-signature>boolean isAllowed(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)</function-signature>
    </function>
</facelet-taglib>
```

I added to the file **web.xml**:

```html
  <context-param>
      <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_LIBRARIES</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/springsecurity.taglib.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
```

After running this page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
 <h:head>
        <title>Login</title>
        <h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery.js"
  target="head" />
 <h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery-plugins.js"
  target="head" />
 </h:head>
 <h:body>
 
  <ui:composition template="/templates/homeTemplate.xhtml"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
         xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
         xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
         xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags"
         xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
  
  
  <ui:define name="content"> 
     <center><h2>Login</h2></center>
  <c:if test="${'fail' eq param.auth}">
      <div style="color:red">
          Login Failed!!!<br/>
             Reason : Bad Credentials!Please Try Again.
      </div>
  </c:if>
      <center>
       <h:form prependId="false" id="form">
          <p:panelGrid columns="2" style="border-bottom-width: 0px;">
                <h:outputText value="UserName:"/>
                <p:inputText value="#{loginController.username}" id="username" required="true" requiredMessage="UserName is required"/>
                <h:outputText value="Password:"/>
                <p:password value="#{loginController.password}" id="password" required="true" requiredMessage="Password is required"/>
            </p:panelGrid>
             <p:spacer height="20px" width="10px">  </p:spacer>
             <p:row>
              <p:selectBooleanCheckbox label="Remember Me" id="remember-me" >Remember Me </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                  <h:outputText value=" " />
             </p:row>
             <br/> 
             <p:row>
              <p:commandButton action="#{loginController.login()}" value="Login" ajax="false"/>
             </p:row>
         </h:form>
  </center>
  </ui:define>
 </ui:composition>
 
 </h:body>
</html>
```

I got this exception:

> SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 175) Critical error during deployment: : com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! org.springframework.faces.security.FaceletsAuthorizeTagHandler from [Module "deployment.mission-man-ear.ear.mission-man-web.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
>       at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:453)
>       at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:227)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:187)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:198)
>       at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:100)
>       at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:82)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>       at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)

After googling, I found this thread [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.faces.security.FaceletsAuthorizeTagHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19260524/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-springframework-faces-security-faceletsaut), but didn't help me!. I think that there's a problem of version of **spring-security-taglibs** ***dependency version***. Have you please any idea about solving this. Any help is appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I's no need to make the new changes.
Try Run As> Maven Clean, Run As> Maven Install then Maven> Update Project.
That's all.

HTH