# <sec:authorize> doesn't work

Tags: authentication, spring-security, xhtml, authorization, facelets

I have the following user xhtml page:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags">
<head>
<title>User</title>
</head>

<body>
    <p>User</p>
    <sec:authorize access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">
        <p>Only admin can see this !</p>
    </sec:authorize>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I access to the page with a user who hasn't the role ROLE_ADMIN, he still can see the "Only admin can see this !"

---

**EDIT:**

Here is my spring security config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.2.xsd">

    <http pattern="/resources" security="none" />

    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/login**" access="permitAll" />

        <intercept-url pattern="/denied**" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/user/*" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin/*" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />


        <form-login login-page="/login.xhtml"
            authentication-failure-url="/denied.xhtml"
            authentication-success-handler-ref="securityAuthenticationSuccessHandler" />

        <access-denied-handler error-page="/denied.xhtml" />

        <logout logout-success-url="/login.xhtml" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID"
            invalidate-session="true" />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="securityProviderServiceImpl">
            <password-encoder hash="md5" />
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

Is there something wrong with it?

Thank you..

---

**EDIT 2 :**

I have a **warning** for the security tag lib **"xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags""**

```
NLS missing message: CANNOT_FIND_FACELET_TAGLIB in: org.eclipse.jst.jsf.core.validation.internal.facelet.messages
```

Is it important? is it the cause of the problem?

My maven security dependencies:

```
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
                <version>${org.springframework.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Config looks right. Did you changed your authority when testing the page without restarting the browser? User authority is session scoped in Spring Security.

Comment: @Conan sorry I don't understand what do you mean by "changing the authority when testing the page without restarting the browser" but I've already tested the page with several users (with different roles, admin and not admin) and each time it does display the "Only admin can see this !"... I think it's simply not recognizing the tag <sec:authorize>.... but why ?

Comment: @Conan (and everybody), am I missing a dependency?

Comment: Another possible solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32904857/secauthorize-returning-true-for-both-isauthenticated-and-isanonymous-in-thy/40492335#40492335

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I solved the problem.

Here is the links which helped me a lot:

1) The answer of "Amreesh Tyagi" here [How to use the Spring Security Facelets tag library in JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7915134/how-to-use-the-spring-security-facelets-tag-library-in-jsf).

and

2) The 3rd part (III Security tags for Facelet) of this article http://doanduyhai.wordpress.com/2012/02/26/spring-security-part-v-security-tags/

I have used the **springsecurity.taglib.xml** file of Amreesh Tyagi rather that the one of the article, because I had a problem whith the access function.

Answer (score 0):

Adding one answer here as I had the same symptoms but found a different issue.
Our  tag was not working as intended. Everyone could see the secured content.
The solution was that our XML namespace was misspelled on the page.

```
 xmlns="http://www.sprinfgramework.org/schema/security"
```

This took a while to find because there was no errors produced with the misspelling (which was surprising), and it simply ignored the security tag and displayed the content it contained.

Hope this helps someone.